# How to compare Date Time Strings format: (YYYY-MM-DD XX:YY) in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

I have a array of these date Times. They are provided as strings. I need to be able to isolate the min dateTime and the max dateTime of the provided array but I am having trouble figuring out how I can do this? 
Is it possible to feed each string to -> new Date(dateTime) and then compare the two objects that way? 
Or do I have to parse then compare the date and compare time separately?

example values:

```
  4: "2018-11-15 00:16"
  5: "2018-11-15 00:52"
  6: "2018-11-15 02:24"
  7: "2018-11-15 03:02"
  8: "2018-11-15 02:49"
  9: "2018-11-15 00:14"
  10: "2018-11-15 02:20"
```

In this example I would need to isolate 9 as the min and 7 as the max value in the array

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort, specifically the `compareFunction` parameter. Should be able to specify that you want each a and b converted to a date and compared using that logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Typescript:

```
const dates = ["2018-11-15 00:16", "2018-11-15 00:52", ...];
const sortedDates = dates.sort();
const minDate = sortedDates[0];
const maxDate = sortedDates[sortedDates.length - 1];
```

And yes you can do :

```
new Date("2018-11-15 00:16") < new Date("2018-11-15 00:52") => true
```

Comment: Use `dates.indexOf(minDate)` to find out the index of the minimum date in the original array.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the other answers I cannot but raise the points that:

- no conversion to `Date` is needed
- sorting has a *O(nlogn)* time complexity, while looking for the min/max can be done in *O(n)* time.

```js
var arr =["2018-11-15 00:16", "2018-11-15 00:52", "2018-11-15 02:24", "2018-11-15 03:02", "2018-11-15 02:49", "2018-11-15 00:14", "2018-11-15 02:20"];

var minDate = arr.reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b);
var maxDate = arr.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);

console.log("min", minDate, "at index", arr.indexOf(minDate));
console.log("max", maxDate, "at index", arr.indexOf(maxDate));
```

Answer (score -1):

**ONELINER**: not fastest ( *O(nlogn)* ) but short code - I assume your strings with dates are in array `a`

```
let min=a.sort()[0], max=a.slice(-1)[0];
```

result is in varaibles `min` and `max`, working example [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mnabj3su/7/)